# $\epsilon-\delta$ proof of a limit of a function $z(x,y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was working on this exercise to prove the differentiability of a function at a certain point, but I got stuck in proving the following limit.

$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^3+4x^2y}{x^2+2y^2} = 0 \>.$

I'm still getting used to deriving the delta-epsilon proof of a limit for functions of many variables, any help is really appreciated!

I'm still getting used to deriving the delta-epsilon proof of a limit for functions of many variables, any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Check [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1231404/does-the-limit-exist-calculus/1231421#1231421).

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$,

$$\left|\frac{x^3 + 4x^2y}{x^2 + 2y^2}\right| \le \frac{|x^3 + 4x^2 y|}{x^2} = |x + 4y| \le |x| + 4|y| \le 5\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}, $$

where the last equality follows from the inequalities $|x| \le \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $|y| \le \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. Now given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $\delta = \epsilon/5$ and conclude $|(x^3 + 4x^2y)/(x^2 + 2y^2)| < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < \delta$.